# Stop before the end of a method and call the other methods

Tags: android, methods, break

I created a method:

```
public void baseOblo ()
```

The method and I started doing the tests, calculations ...

As a result do to stop the method is invalid, or not to continue the remaining codes and the method call another method `public void baseCirc ()`

?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you reach a point in `baseOblo` where you no longer want to continue processing, and instead want to call a new method?  If so:

```
public void baseOblo (){

    // do stuff

    if(someCondition == true){
        baseCirc();
        return;
    }

     // do other stuff

}
```